# How to update only some properties in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to update only *Status* and *Country* Properties and hence want to prevent *Sign* Property to be updated on Edit.

**Here is my Model class**

```
public class Currency{
        [Required]
        public int Id{ get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string Sign { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Status{get;set;}
    }
```

This is the default Edit method in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Sign,Country,Status")] Currency currenc)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(currenc).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
             return View(currenc);
        }
```

Comment: [What is ViewModel in MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: you want me to write view also in question

Comment: No - I want you to read the link :)

Answer (score 1):

**Write the Edit method as follows:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Sign,Country,Status")] Currency currenc)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(currenc).State = EntityState.Modified;

                 // Sign Property wouldn't be updated
                db.Entry(currenc).Property(x => x.Sign).IsModified = false;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
             return View(currenc);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the object from the database, update only the properties that has been changed or you want to change and save it back to the database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Currency currency)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var record = db.Currencies.Find(currency.Id);
            if(record != null)
              {
                record.Status = currency.Status;
                record.Country = currency.Country;
                db.SaveChanges();
              }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
         return View(currenc);
    }
```

Comment: it's secure to remove bindings(Bind(Include = )

Comment: Yes because you are not using the object itself but using it to set the properties in the other object loaded from the database